# Ordering Checkbox and its label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am working in the Oracle CPQ tool, and I'm trying to create a checkbox as an attribute.

In the UI I am getting the following:

[image]

When reviewed in the browser source (which is generated by the CPQ tool), I can see the following HTML code:

```
<div class="form-item clearfix null" id="attr_wrapper_1_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" style="display: table;">
<label class="form-label" for="chkmembershipFeePayment_t" style="width: 100px">
    <span style="padding-right: 5px;display: table-cell;">Membership Fee</span>
</label>
<div class="form-element field-wrapper" id="field_wrapper_1_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" style="padding-left:100px">
    <div class="boolean-wrapper field" message="" style="display: table-cell;">
        <div class="boolean-wrapper-inner"><input value="false" class=" form-input  cm-attr-value " name="chkmembershipFeePayment_t" onclick="if (this.checked) { this.value='true'; } else { this.value='false'; }" data-is-boolean="true" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <input value="true" name="_boolean_present_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" type="hidden">
    </div>
    <div id="msg_1_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" class="error-hover" data-action-message="" message=""></div>
</div>
::after</div>
```

My question is: How can I switch the checkbox and the label, placing the checkbox *before* the label 'Membership free' using CSS or JavaScript, considering I cannot directly edit the HTML using the CPQ tool attribute.

So any way to do that?

**After Sagar V** updated javascript

[image]

Comment: did the answer worked for you?

Comment: no it is not working. even i check in console for exception but its blank. Am checking for anything i forgot to deploy.

Comment: In the snippet, what did you see? working or not?

Comment: any update @V.Rohan ?

Comment: @Sagar V it is not working because of more than one label on page ?

Comment: update your code then I can show you a valid selector.

Comment: i already mentioned one Parent <div>

Comment: Check the answer now. It is updated. And let me know if it is worked as expected or not.

Comment: I am updating image in question, kindly check.

Comment: can you add more code. it is a problem with css or normal alignment.

Comment: help of your code and little on CSS its worked thank you @Sagar V

Comment: glad it helped mate. I think the CSS should be  display inline or inline-block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The JavaScript

- get the label element
- remove it from original position
- add it after the input

```js
elm = document.querySelector('label[for=chkmembershipFeePayment_t]');

target = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");

elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);

target.parentNode.insertBefore(elm, target.nextSibling);
```

```html
<label class="form-label" for="chkmembershipFeePayment_t" style="width: 100px">
<span style="padding-right: 5px">Membership Fee</span>
</label>
<div class="form-element field-wrapper" id="field_wrapper_1_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" style="padding-left:100px">
  <div class="boolean-wrapper field" message="">
    <div class="boolean-wrapper-inner">
      <input value="false" class=" form-input  cm-attr-value " name="chkmembershipFeePayment_t" onclick="if (this.checked) { this.value='true'; } else { this.value='false'; }" data-is-boolean="true" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <input value="true" name="_boolean_present_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" type="hidden">
  </div>
  <div id="msg_1_chkmembershipFeePayment_t" class="error-hover" data-action-message="" message=""></div>
```